# Updating a Field with the value of a Look Up Field

Tags: list-view

I have a problem I can't solve.

I'm recording the relationships between Mentors and Mentees.

We capture 'matches' via Look Up Fields.

[image]

I can only see this match in List view on the Mentee side.

On the mentor side, it's in the Related List.

[image]

How can I get a field to autoupdate with the Mentee so I can view all the matches in List View from the Mentor side? ie to be displayed in a list like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture for better understanding

Comment: Thanks Santaun - I'll edit the original questions with some examples

Comment: Ok Santuanu - I've added examples

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you cannot show the "many" side of a one-to-many relationship like this on a list view on the "one" side. Why? Because there's many values, and it's not clear what the right way to show that would be in a list view context, where what you expect is one row per record. Salesforce doesn't have native modeling for one-to-one relationships.

Note that you *can* do this in a report, and you'll get what you might expect if you have SQL joins in your head - as many rows for each Mentor as that Mentor has Mentees, with the Mentor information repeated for each Mentee.

If what you're working with is actually a one-to-one relationship (i.e., each Mentor will only ever have one Mentee, full stop), you can use a Process Builder automation. You'd attach it to the Mentee object, and configure it to update a "Mentee" link on the "Mentor" every time the Mentee is updated. Then you'd actually have a field on the Mentor that you can show in a list view.

Contrariwise, if what you have is more like a many-to-many relationship, it may be that the right data model for you is a junction object: a record representing the match itself, with master-detail relationships to both the Mentor and the Mentee. Your list views could be built on this Match object, and would show the details of both Mentor and Mentee - as well as any other metadata you chose to add to the match, like its active dates or status.

Keeping the data model you have and not treating it as one-to-one, the only route I can see to get this information in a list view is to use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries to populate a Text field on the Mentor with a concatenated list of Mentees' names. You can do this with a rollup in the "Concatenate Distinct" mode.

Comment: Thanks David - this is a really helpful answer - As always with SF there's a lot of complexity when you ask for something which appears simple! 

The relationship actually changes year by year so a Mentor will work with different Mentees over their their years working with us - this is why we capture the data in a Related List. 

Thanks for your detailed reply, I'll work on a resolution with it.

Comment: @JamesPowell Based on that, I would strongly recommend you utilize a Junction Object, which will allow you to track metadata (like Year) for the relationship.